# Azure AD OpenID Connect

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, openid

I started working on integrating Azure AD with OpenId Connect. I tried to run the sample locally:
https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/resources/samples/active-directory-java-webapp-openidconnect/

But the app redirects me to the error page giving me a HTTP 403 error. So I took the debugger and the portion where I get thrown out is this bit:

```
 private String getUsernamesFromGraph(String accessToken, String tenant) throws Exception {


        URL url = new URL("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users");


        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
        int httpResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

        String goodRespStr = HttpClientHelper.getResponseStringFromConn(conn, true);
```

So I took the access token and all the other headers and put it into postman to see the response from the graph service. The response looks like this:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
        "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "XXXXXX-fa72-XXXX-8f56-d989a4879843",
            "date": "2018-08-15T07:18:48"
        }
    }
}
```

But to my knowledge I have granted each and every role to the Azure AD app:
[Granted roles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TaSd.png)

If I take a peek at my dummy users sign in history in Azure Portal I see that the sign-ins were successfull:
[sign-ins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAgJJ.png)

What did I miss during configuration?

Comment: I'm guessing the access token was acquired using e.g. an authorization code. Then only delegated permissions apply, as there is a user context. If you want to use application permissions, you need to acquire the token using client credentials (you just change your acquireToken() call to use a different overload).

Comment: I must confess this was my first hour fiddeling around with the example and I do not really understand what you mean - there is no acquireToken in the sample code.

Comment: No problem, they are doing it here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-java-webapp-openidconnect/blob/master/src/main/java/com/microsoft/aad/adal4jsample/BasicFilter.java#L275. But if you want to use app permissions, you'll need to do it somewhere you are making that call, not in this filter. You can leave the filter in as it is, but implement acquiring the token using client credentials at the location where you make the API call.

Comment: Thanks I got it to work !

Comment: Great! You should be able to post an answer to the question, just show the essential parts of how you solved it.